# Switched to a Linux Environment, now fscanf doesn't work

Tags: linux, portability, qt-creator, scanf

I have a program that works when compiled in Windows with both Visual Studio and CodeBlocks, but when I compile it in Kubuntu using QT Creator, the fscanf functions don't work the same way.

I have a file containing the names of other files, each of which is separated by a space and line break. Using fscanf with "%s" in the working environments reads the file name into `char entity[21]` which, in this test case, holds "ent001.txt" and ends in a null byte. In linux, however, entity[0] has "-74 / 182" then several null bytes, then several things that aren't in the file being read, none of them letters. Fscanf returns a -1.

Is there a deeper problem in portability, or are my standard libraries a bit off?

EDIT: For some sample code:

```
    fin = fopen( levelfile, "r" ) ;

    test = fscanf(fin, "%s", entity ) ;
```

Where 'levelfile' is 'char* levelfile[21]' whose value is hard coded in right now. Test is an 'int' to find the return value. 'fin' is not equal to null.

EDIT2: Output from xxd on the level file:

```
0000000: 656e 7430 3031 2e74 7874 200a 656e 7430  ent001.txt .ent0
0000010: 3032 2e74 7874 2024 200a 5472 6967 6765  02.txt $ .Trigge
0000020: 7230 3031 2e74 7874 2024 200a 3020 3531  r001.txt $ .0 51
0000030: 3220 3531 3220 3020 0a31 2037 3132 2037  2 512 0 .1 712 7
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how you expect us to be able to answer this...

Comment: What about an example code? :)

Comment: 1. Where's the code? 2. If fscanf returns a negative value, you shouldn't expect `entity` to contain anything meaningful. Check for a previous error condition in your code that you're not catching.

Comment: There's some sample code now. I can provide more, but don't know what else would be helpful. These two calls are at the beginning of a function with only one argument, 'levelfile'.

Comment: Are you compiling with warnings enabled (-Wall -Wextra)?  Can you reproduce the error with a minimal code snippet?  Paring down the code to reproduce the error in a small case will often reveal the source of the problem.

Comment: Is it char *levelfile[ 21 ] or char levelfile[ 21 ]?  It should be the latter.

Comment: It's char levelfile[21]. And it may be worth noting that running some simple code that just calls 'fopen', 'fscanf', 'printf' and 'fclose' works fine when using emacs and g++ from a command line, but not when build from Qt Creator.

Answer (score 1):

Where did your data file get created?  Any chance it has DOS-style line breaks (CR+LF) instead of Unix newlines?

If that's the problem, then text-mode (`fopen(fname, "rt")`) may help or you can run the file through the `dos2unix` utility (just `d2u` on some Linus distributions).

Comment: Tried both of those, the problem persists. And the files were made in a Windows environment using Notepad++.

Comment: Can you run `hexdump` or `xxd` on the file and attach the 2-3 lines of output to your question?  Does the first call to `fscanf` fail, or later calls?

Comment: It is the first call to 'fscanf' in the program that fails, and added to the question.

Comment: @Lucas: Well, you've definitely got the right newline characters.